# Chat Heads overlay Cannot resolve method

Tags: android, notifications, chat, head, bubble-popup

I got the Chat head built, but when I try to start it when a message arrives with this code:

```
        Intent i = new Intent(this, ChatHeadDrawerService.class);
        this.startService(i);
```

I get an "Cannot resolve method" error.

```
public void onNewChatMessageContact(String senderTitle, int senderId, String chatTitle, int chatId, int mid, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(mid, senderTitle, senderId, application.getString(R.string.st_notification_group_sent_contact)
            .replace("{name}", senderTitle)
            .replace("{chat}", chatTitle), PeerType.PEER_CHAT, chatId, photo);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ChatHeadDrawerService.class);
    this.startService(i);
}

public void onNewChatMessageVideo(String senderTitle, int senderId, String chatTitle, int chatId, int mid, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(mid, senderTitle, senderId, application.getString(R.string.st_notification_group_sent_video)
            .replace("{name}", senderTitle)
            .replace("{chat}", chatTitle), PeerType.PEER_CHAT, chatId, photo);
}

public void onNewChatMessagePhoto(String senderTitle, int senderId, String chatTitle, int chatId, int mid, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(mid, senderTitle, senderId, application.getString(R.string.st_notification_group_sent_photo)
            .replace("{name}", senderTitle)
            .replace("{chat}", chatTitle), PeerType.PEER_CHAT, chatId, photo);
}

public void onNewChatMessage(String senderTitle, int senderId, String chatTitle, String message, int chatId, int mid, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(mid, senderTitle + "@" + chatTitle, senderId, message, PeerType.PEER_CHAT, chatId, photo);
}
```

This is the full code for that.

This is the Service:

```
 <service android:name="org.telegram.android.ChatHeadDrawerService"
        android:enabled="true" />
```

Where's my error?

Full code for Notifications.java:

```
public class Notifications {

private class NotificationConfig {
    public boolean useSound;
    public boolean useNotification;
    public boolean useInAppNotification;
    public boolean useVibration;
    public boolean useCustomSound;
    public String customSoundUri;
}

private static final String TAG = "Notificagtions";

private static final long QUITE_PERIOD = 300;
private static final long IN_APP_TIMEOUT = 3000;

private static final int MAX_SENDER_LENGTH = 100;
private static final int MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH = 200;

private static final long[] VIBRATE_PATTERN = new long[]{0, 200};
private static final int NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE = 0;
private static final int NOTIFICATION_SYSTEM = 1;

private TelegramApplication application;
private NotificationManager manager;

private int lastNotifiedMid = -1;
private long lastNotifiedTime = -1;

private int lastPeerId;
private int lastPeerType;

private Random rnd = new Random();

private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper()) {
    @Override
    public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
        Logger.d(TAG, "notify");
        hideInApp();
    }
};

private SoundPool pool;
private int soundId;

private View notificationView;
private Activity notificationActivity;
private WindowManager windowManager;

public Notifications(TelegramApplication application) {
    this.application = application;
    this.windowManager = (WindowManager) application.getSystemService(Context.WINDOW_SERVICE);
    this.manager = (NotificationManager) application.getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
    this.pool = new SoundPool(1, AudioManager.STREAM_NOTIFICATION, 0);
    this.soundId = this.pool.load(application, R.raw.message, 0);
}

public void onActivityPaused() {
    hideInAppNow();
}

public void hideInApp() {
    if (notificationActivity != null) {
        AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(1.0F, 0.0f);
        alpha.setDuration(250);
        alpha.setFillAfter(true);
        notificationView.findViewById(R.id.mainContainer).startAnimation(alpha);
        final View view = notificationView;
        notificationView.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                windowManager.removeView(view);
            }
        }, 300);
        notificationView = null;
        notificationActivity = null;
        Logger.d(TAG, "Hide in-app");
    }
}

public void hideInAppNow() {
    if (notificationActivity != null) {
        windowManager.removeView(notificationView);
        notificationView = null;
        notificationActivity = null;
        Logger.d(TAG, "Hide in-app fast");
    }
}

public synchronized void onNewSystemMessage(String message) {
    NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(application);
    builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_notify);
    builder.setTicker(message);
    builder.setContentTitle("Atom");
    builder.setContentText(message);
    builder.setContentIntent(
            PendingIntent.getActivity(application, 0, new Intent().setClass(application, StartActivity.class), 0));
    manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_SYSTEM, builder.build());
}

public void onAuthUnrecognized(String deviceName) {
    onNewSystemMessage(application.getString(R.string.st_notification_new_login).replace("{device}", deviceName));
}

public void onAuthUnrecognized(String deviceName, String loc) {
    onNewSystemMessage(application.getString(R.string.st_notification_new_login_location)
            .replace("{device}", deviceName)
            .replace("{location}", loc));
}

// Private chats

public void onNewMessageGeo(String senderTitle, int uid, int mid, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(mid, senderTitle, uid,
            application.getString(R.string.st_notification_sent_map)
                    .replace("{name}", senderTitle),
            PeerType.PEER_USER, uid, photo);
}

public void onNewMessageDoc(String senderTitle, int uid, int mid, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(mid, senderTitle, uid,
            application.getString(R.string.st_notification_sent_document)
                    .replace("{name}", senderTitle),
            PeerType.PEER_USER, uid, photo);
}

public void onNewMessageAudio(String senderTitle, int uid, int mid, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(mid, senderTitle, uid,
            application.getString(R.string.st_notification_sent_audio)
                    .replace("{name}", senderTitle),
            PeerType.PEER_USER, uid, photo);
}

public void onNewMessageContact(String senderTitle, int uid, int mid, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(mid, senderTitle, uid,
            application.getString(R.string.st_notification_sent_contact)
                    .replace("{name}", senderTitle)
            , PeerType.PEER_USER, uid, photo);
}

public void onNewMessageVideo(String senderTitle, int uid, int mid, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(mid, senderTitle, uid,
            application.getString(R.string.st_notification_sent_video)
                    .replace("{name}", senderTitle)
            , PeerType.PEER_USER, uid, photo);
}

public void onNewMessagePhoto(String senderTitle, int uid, int mid, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(mid, senderTitle, uid,
            application.getString(R.string.st_notification_sent_photo)
                    .replace("{name}", senderTitle)
            , PeerType.PEER_USER, uid, photo);
}

public void onNewMessage(String senderTitle, String message, int uid, int mid, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(mid, senderTitle, uid, message, PeerType.PEER_USER, uid, photo);
}

public void onNewMessageJoined(String senderTitle, int uid, int mid, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(mid, senderTitle, uid,
            application.getString(R.string.st_notification_joined)
                    .replace("{name}", senderTitle), PeerType.PEER_USER, uid, photo);
}

// Group chats

public void onNewChatMessageGeo(String senderTitle, int senderId, String chatTitle, int chatId, int mid, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(mid, senderTitle, senderId,
            application.getString(R.string.st_notification_group_sent_map)
                    .replace("{name}", senderTitle)
                    .replace("{chat}", chatTitle), PeerType.PEER_CHAT, chatId, photo);
}

public void onNewChatMessageDoc(String senderTitle, int senderId, String chatTitle, int chatId, int mid, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(mid, senderTitle, senderId,
            application.getString(R.string.st_notification_group_sent_document)
                    .replace("{name}", senderTitle)
                    .replace("{chat}", chatTitle), PeerType.PEER_CHAT, chatId, photo);
}

public void onNewChatMessageAudio(String senderTitle, int senderId, String chatTitle, int chatId, int mid, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(mid, senderTitle, senderId,
            application.getString(R.string.st_notification_group_sent_audio)
                    .replace("{name}", senderTitle)
                    .replace("{chat}", chatTitle), PeerType.PEER_CHAT, chatId, photo);
}

public void onNewChatMessageContact(String senderTitle, int senderId, String chatTitle, int chatId, int mid, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(mid, senderTitle, senderId, application.getString(R.string.st_notification_group_sent_contact)
            .replace("{name}", senderTitle)
            .replace("{chat}", chatTitle), PeerType.PEER_CHAT, chatId, photo);
    Intent i = new Intent(this, ChatHeadDrawerService.class);
    this.startService(i);
}

public void onNewChatMessageVideo(String senderTitle, int senderId, String chatTitle, int chatId, int mid, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(mid, senderTitle, senderId, application.getString(R.string.st_notification_group_sent_video)
            .replace("{name}", senderTitle)
            .replace("{chat}", chatTitle), PeerType.PEER_CHAT, chatId, photo);
}

public void onNewChatMessagePhoto(String senderTitle, int senderId, String chatTitle, int chatId, int mid, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(mid, senderTitle, senderId, application.getString(R.string.st_notification_group_sent_photo)
            .replace("{name}", senderTitle)
            .replace("{chat}", chatTitle), PeerType.PEER_CHAT, chatId, photo);
}

public void onNewChatMessage(String senderTitle, int senderId, String chatTitle, String message, int chatId, int mid, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(mid, senderTitle + "@" + chatTitle, senderId, message, PeerType.PEER_CHAT, chatId, photo);
}

// Secret chats

public void onNewSecretMessage(String senderTitle, int senderId, int chatId, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(0, senderTitle, senderId, application.getString(R.string.st_notification_secret_sent_message),
            PeerType.PEER_USER_ENCRYPTED, chatId, photo);
}

public void onNewSecretChatRequested(String senderTitle, int senderId, int chatId, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(0, senderTitle, senderId, application.getString(R.string.st_notification_secret_requested),
            PeerType.PEER_USER_ENCRYPTED, chatId, photo);
}

public void onNewSecretChatEstablished(String senderTitle, int senderId, int chatId, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(0, senderTitle, senderId, application.getString(R.string.st_notification_secret_created),
            PeerType.PEER_USER_ENCRYPTED, chatId, photo);
}

public void onNewSecretChatCancelled(String senderTitle, int senderId, int chatId, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(0, senderTitle, senderId, application.getString(R.string.st_notification_secret_cancelled),
            PeerType.PEER_USER_ENCRYPTED, chatId, photo);
}

public void onNewSecretMessageVideo(String senderTitle, int senderId, int chatId, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(0, senderTitle, senderId, application.getString(R.string.st_notification_secret_sent_video),
            PeerType.PEER_USER_ENCRYPTED, chatId, photo);
}

public void onNewSecretMessagePhoto(String senderTitle, int senderId, int chatId, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(0, senderTitle, senderId, application.getString(R.string.st_notification_secret_sent_photo),
            PeerType.PEER_USER_ENCRYPTED, chatId, photo);
}

public void onNewSecretMessageGeo(String senderTitle, int senderId, int chatId, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(0, senderTitle, senderId, application.getString(R.string.st_notification_secret_sent_map),
            PeerType.PEER_USER_ENCRYPTED, chatId, photo);
}

public void onNewSecretMessageDoc(String senderTitle, int senderId, int chatId, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(0, senderTitle, senderId, application.getString(R.string.st_notification_secret_sent_doc),
            PeerType.PEER_USER_ENCRYPTED, chatId, photo);
}

public void onNewSecretMessageAudio(String senderTitle, int senderId, int chatId, TLObject photo) {
    notifyMessage(0, senderTitle, senderId, application.getString(R.string.st_notification_secret_sent_audio),
            PeerType.PEER_USER_ENCRYPTED, chatId, photo);
}

private void notifyApp(final NotificationConfig config, String senderTitle, final int senderId, String message, final int peerType, final int peerId, final TLObject photo) {

    if (senderTitle.length() > MAX_SENDER_LENGTH) {
        senderTitle = senderTitle.substring(MAX_SENDER_LENGTH) + "...";
    }

    if (message.length() > MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH) {
        message = message.substring(MAX_MESSAGE_LENGTH) + "...";
    }

    message = application.getEmojiProcessor().fixStringCompat(message);

    if (config.useNotification) {
        NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(application);
        builder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.app_notify);

        builder.setTicker(senderTitle + ": " + message);

        builder.setContentTitle(senderTitle);
        builder.setContentText(message);

        Intent intent = new Intent(StartActivity.ACTION_OPEN_CHAT);
        intent.setClass(application, StartActivity.class);
        intent.putExtra("peerType", peerType);
        intent.putExtra("peerId", peerId);
        builder.setContentIntent(PendingIntent.getActivity(application, rnd.nextInt(), intent, 0));
        Bitmap bigPhoto = null;
        if (photo != null) {
            if (photo instanceof TLLocalAvatarPhoto) {
                TLLocalAvatarPhoto profilePhoto = (TLLocalAvatarPhoto) photo;
                if (profilePhoto.getPreviewLocation() instanceof TLLocalFileLocation) {
                    bigPhoto = application.getImageController().addTask(new StelsImageTask((TLLocalFileLocation) profilePhoto.getPreviewLocation()));
                }
            }
        }

        if (bigPhoto == null) {
            if (peerType == PeerType.PEER_USER || peerType == PeerType.PEER_USER_ENCRYPTED) {
                BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable)
                        application.getResources().getDrawable(Placeholders.getUserPlaceholder(Math.abs(senderId)));
                bigPhoto = drawable.getBitmap();
            } else {
                BitmapDrawable drawable = (BitmapDrawable)
                        application.getResources().getDrawable(Placeholders.getGroupPlaceholder(Math.abs(peerId)));
                bigPhoto = drawable.getBitmap();
            }
        }
        builder.setLargeIcon(bigPhoto);

        if (peerType == PeerType.PEER_USER || peerType == PeerType.PEER_USER_ENCRYPTED) {
            builder.setLights(Placeholders.USER_PLACEHOLDERS_COLOR[Math.abs(senderId) % Placeholders.USER_PLACEHOLDERS_COLOR.length], 1500, 1500);
        } else {
            builder.setLights(Placeholders.GROUP_PLACEHOLDERS_COLOR[Math.abs(peerId) % Placeholders.GROUP_PLACEHOLDERS_COLOR.length], 1500, 1500);
        }

        int defaults = 0;

        if (config.useSound) {
            if (config.useCustomSound) {
                builder.setSound(Uri.parse(config.customSoundUri));
            } else {
                defaults = defaults | Notification.DEFAULT_SOUND;
            }
        }

        if (config.useVibration) {
            builder.setVibrate(VIBRATE_PATTERN);
        }

        builder.setDefaults(defaults);

        manager.notify(NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE, builder.build());
    } else {

        if (config.useSound) {
            if (config.useInAppNotification) {
                Uri soundUri;
                if (config.useCustomSound) {
                    soundUri = Uri.parse(config.customSoundUri);
                } else {
                    soundUri = RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
                }

                try {
                    Ringtone r = RingtoneManager.getRingtone(application, soundUri);
                    r.play();
                } catch (Exception e) {
                }

            } else {
                pool.play(soundId, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1);
            }
        }
        if (config.useVibration) {
            Vibrator mVibrator = (Vibrator) application.getSystemService(Context.VIBRATOR_SERVICE);
            mVibrator.vibrate(VIBRATE_PATTERN, -1);
        }

        if (config.useInAppNotification) {
            final String finalMessage = message;
            final String finalSenderTitle = senderTitle;
            handler.post(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    final Activity activity = application.getUiKernel().getVisibleActivity();
                    if (activity == null) {
                        return;
                    }

                    boolean needAdd = false;
                    if (notificationView == null) {
                        notificationView = activity.getLayoutInflater().inflate(R.layout.notification_inapp, null);
                        notificationView.findViewById(R.id.closeButton).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onClick(View v) {
                                hideInApp();
                            }
                        });
                        notificationActivity = activity;
                        needAdd = true;
                    }

                    ((TextView) notificationView.findViewById(R.id.name)).setText(finalSenderTitle);
                    ((TextView) notificationView.findViewById(R.id.title)).setText(finalMessage);

                    FastWebImageView avatarImage = (FastWebImageView) notificationView.findViewById(R.id.avatar);
                    if (peerType == PeerType.PEER_USER) {
                        avatarImage.setLoadingDrawable(Placeholders.getUserPlaceholder(peerId));
                        ((TextView) notificationView.findViewById(R.id.name)).setTextColor(Placeholders.getUserTitleColor(peerId));
                        ((TextView) notificationView.findViewById(R.id.name)).setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null);
                    } else if (peerType == PeerType.PEER_CHAT) {
                        avatarImage.setLoadingDrawable(Placeholders.getGroupPlaceholder(peerId));
                        ((TextView) notificationView.findViewById(R.id.name)).setTextColor(Placeholders.getGroupTitleColor(peerId));
                        ((TextView) notificationView.findViewById(R.id.name)).setCompoundDrawables(null, null, null, null);
                    } else {
                        avatarImage.setLoadingDrawable(Placeholders.getUserPlaceholder(senderId));
                        ((TextView) notificationView.findViewById(R.id.name)).setTextColor(0xff67b540);
                        ((TextView) notificationView.findViewById(R.id.name)).setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.st_ic_lock_green, 0, 0, 0);
                    }

                    notificationView.findViewById(R.id.container).setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onClick(View v) {
                            ((RootControllerHolder) activity).getRootController().openDialog(peerType, peerId);
                            hideInApp();
                        }
                    });

                    avatarImage.requestTask(null);
                    if (photo != null) {
                        if (photo instanceof TLLocalAvatarPhoto) {
                            TLLocalAvatarPhoto profilePhoto = (TLLocalAvatarPhoto) photo;
                            if (profilePhoto.getPreviewLocation() instanceof TLLocalFileLocation) {
                                avatarImage.requestTask(new StelsImageTask((TLLocalFileLocation) profilePhoto.getPreviewLocation()));
                            } else {
                                avatarImage.requestTask(null);
                            }
                        } else {
                            avatarImage.requestTask(null);
                        }
                    } else {
                        avatarImage.requestTask(null);
                    }


                    if (needAdd) {
                        AlphaAnimation alpha = new AlphaAnimation(0.0F, 1.0f);
                        alpha.setDuration(250);
                        alpha.setFillAfter(true);
                        notificationView.setFocusable(false);
                        notificationView.findViewById(R.id.mainContainer).setFocusable(false);
                        notificationView.findViewById(R.id.mainContainer).startAnimation(alpha);

                        WindowManager.LayoutParams params = new WindowManager.LayoutParams();
                        params.height = (int) (application.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().density * 48);
                        params.format = PixelFormat.TRANSLUCENT;
                        params.flags = WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_IN_SCREEN
                                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_WATCH_OUTSIDE_TOUCH
                                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_FOCUSABLE
                                | WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_LAYOUT_NO_LIMITS;
                        params.type = WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_ERROR;
                        params.gravity = Gravity.CLIP_HORIZONTAL | Gravity.TOP;

                        windowManager.addView(notificationView, params);
                    }

                    handler.removeMessages(0);
                    handler.sendEmptyMessageDelayed(0, IN_APP_TIMEOUT);
                }
            });
        }
    }
}

private synchronized void notifyMessage(int mid, String senderTitle, int senderId, String message, int peerType, int peerId, TLObject photo) {
    if (mid <= lastNotifiedMid && mid != 0) {
        Logger.d(TAG, "Ignoring old message");
        return;
    }

    ChatMessage msg = application.getEngine().getMessagesEngine().getMessageByMid(mid);
    if (msg != null) {
        if (msg.isOut()) {
            Logger.d(TAG, "Ignoring out message");
            return;
        }

        if (msg.getState() == MessageState.READED) {
            Logger.d(TAG, "Ignoring readed message");
            return;
        }
    }

    if (mid != 0) {
        lastNotifiedMid = mid;
    }

    lastPeerId = peerId;
    lastPeerType = peerType;

    NotificationSettings settings = application.getNotificationSettings();

    if (!settings.isEnabled()) {
        Logger.d(TAG, "Notifications disabled");
        return;
    }


    if (peerType == PeerType.PEER_USER || peerType == PeerType.PEER_USER_ENCRYPTED) {
        if (!settings.isEnabledForUser(senderId)) {
            Logger.d(TAG, "Notifications disabled for user");
            return;
        }
        if (senderId == application.getCurrentUid()) {
            return;
        }
    } else {
        if (!settings.isGroupEnabled()) {
            Logger.d(TAG, "Group notifications disabled");
            return;
        }

        if (!settings.isEnabledForChat(peerId)) {
            Logger.d(TAG, "Notifications disabled for chat");
            return;
        }
    }

    NotificationConfig config = new NotificationConfig();

    if (peerType == PeerType.PEER_USER || peerType == PeerType.PEER_USER_ENCRYPTED) {
        config.useVibration = settings.isMessageVibrationEnabled();
        config.useSound = settings.isMessageSoundEnabled();
        if (settings.getUserNotificationSound(senderId) != null) {
            config.customSoundUri = settings.getUserNotificationSound(senderId);
            config.useCustomSound = false;
        } else {
            config.customSoundUri = settings.getNotificationSound();
            config.useCustomSound = config.customSoundUri != null;
        }
    } else {
        config.useVibration = settings.isGroupVibrateEnabled();
        config.useSound = settings.isGroupSoundEnabled();

        if (settings.getChatNotificationSound(peerId) != null) {
            config.customSoundUri = settings.getChatNotificationSound(peerId);
            config.useCustomSound = true;
        } else if (settings.getNotificationGroupSound() != null) {
            config.customSoundUri = settings.getNotificationGroupSound();
            config.useCustomSound = true;
        } else {
            config.customSoundUri = settings.getNotificationSound();
            config.useCustomSound = config.customSoundUri != null;
        }
    }

    boolean isConversationVisible = false;

    if (application.getUiKernel().isAppVisible()) {
        config.useSound = config.useSound & settings.isInAppSoundsEnabled();
        config.useVibration = config.useVibration & settings.isInAppVibrateEnabled();
        if (application.getUiKernel().getOpenedChatPeerType() == peerType && application.getUiKernel().getOpenedChatPeerId() == peerId || application.getUiKernel().isDialogsVisible()) {
            config.useNotification = false;
            config.useInAppNotification = false;
            isConversationVisible = true;
        } else {
            config.useNotification = false;
            config.useInAppNotification = settings.isInAppPreviewEnabled();
        }
    } else {
        config.useNotification = true;
        config.useInAppNotification = false;
    }

    if (SystemClock.uptimeMillis() - lastNotifiedTime < QUITE_PERIOD && !isConversationVisible) {
        config.useVibration = false;
        config.useSound = false;
    } else {
        lastNotifiedTime = SystemClock.uptimeMillis();
    }

    Logger.d(TAG, "Performing notification");
    notifyApp(config, senderTitle, senderId, message, peerType, peerId, photo);
}

public void hideChatNotifications(int peerType, int peerId) {
    if (lastPeerType == peerType && lastPeerId == peerId) {
        manager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE);
    }
}

public void hideAllNotifications() {
    manager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_MESSAGE);
    manager.cancel(NOTIFICATION_SYSTEM);
}

public void reset() {
    hideAllNotifications();
    lastNotifiedMid = 0;
    lastNotifiedTime = 0;
}
```

}

Comment: What is `this`? (An Activity, a Service, ...). Also, please post your Manifest definition for your Service.

Comment: Here's the full code for Notifications.java and the service...

Comment: Update the answer with the stacktrace, and point the error line to the code you've uploaded.

Answer (score 0):

Your custom `Notifications` class does not have a method called `startService()`, this is why you get a compilation error. You need a `Context` object to call `startService()` on it.

Comment: How can I get this Context object?

Comment: @user3272495, The easiest option - pass it as a parameter to the constructor.

Comment: How do I have to do this?

Comment: @user3272495, Sorry if I'm being rude, but if you don't know how to pass an additional argument to your class's constructor, then maybe you should learn some Java development prior to developing Android applications.

Comment: Sorry, but I'm learning... Could you tell me how to do that, please?

Answer (score 0):

```
<service android:name="org.telegram.android.ChatHeadDrawerService"
         android:enabled="true" />
```

Since you're assigning an action name to your `Service`, simply use it within your `Intent`.

```
  Intent intent = new Intent("org.telegram.android.ChatHeadDrawerService");  
  this.startService(intent);
```

Comment: It still can't find the startService method. This is the main Problem.